Clickhouse + asynch
I have a problem with async migrations alembic to Clickhouse
When running the command alembic upgrade head, I get the following error:
(reporting3.11) PS D:\Projects\work\reporting\reporting> alembic upgrade head                       
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl ClickHouseDialectImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> fc4badfc681a, empty message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 641, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 631, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 608, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Projects\work\reporting\reporting\migrations\env.py", line 100, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "D:\Projects\work\reporting\reporting\migrations\env.py", line 94, in run_migrations_online
    asyncio.run(run_async_migrations())
  File "C:\Users\Ira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Ira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Ira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\work\reporting\reporting\migrations\env.py", line 86, in run_async_migrations
    await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 886, in run_sync
    return await greenlet_spawn(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 201, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\work\reporting\reporting\migrations\env.py", line 70, in do_run_migrations
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 616, in run_migrations
    with self.begin_transaction(_per_migration=True):
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 84, in __exit__
    self._proxied_transaction.__exit__(type_, value, traceback)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\util.py", line 147, in __exit__
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\util.py", line 145, in __exit__
    self.commit()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2633, in commit
    self._do_commit()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2738, in _do_commit
    self._connection_commit_impl()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2709, in _connection_commit_impl
    self.connection._commit_impl()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1150, in _commit_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2360, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1148, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 696, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_sqlalchemy\drivers\asynch\connector.py", line 182, in commit
    self.await_(self._connection.commit())
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 131, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 196, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\env\reporting3.11\Lib\site-packages\asynch\connection.py", line 90, in commit
    raise errors.NotSupportedError
asynch.errors.NotSupportedError: Code: None.

My DSN
dsn: str = f"clickhouse+asynch://{CLICKHOUSE_USER}:{CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD}@" \ f"{CLICKHOUSE_HOST}:{CLICKHOUSE_PORT}/{CLICKHOUSE_DB}"
I can't find the cause of the error, there is very little information on asynch.
maybe someone has encountered and solved the problem?

Look to your migrations code
Alembic try to execute commit()
ClickHouse doesn't have transaction
And asynch return NonSupportedError
https://github.com/long2ice/asynch/blob/dev/asynch/connection.py#L89
Try remove +asynch in your DSN
https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy-alembic-example/
